# Watched Tags: no coloring questions

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, tagging, user-interface

In the panel on the right I have highlighted a few tags that are my favorites. This generated a light pastel color  that let me know that the question was among my favorites and referred to a tag in my list. This option has disappeared and I wanted to know if you have the same problem or if there is work in progress.

Here I put an example where there is not the light pastel color.

[image]

Comment: These types of problems are usually network-wide, so if you go to https://meta.stackexchange.com you can usually find someone who spotted the issue before you: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/366321/383578.

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik Thank you for your advice. I am not expert to site....a bit on TeX.Se :-). Thank you very much for your links.

Comment: That should be working again soon, see https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/366345

Comment: @campa Hi and thank you very much also for you. +1 for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

To the 22:48 (about) GMT+1 of 2021-06-10 it has been recreated the light background color.

[image]